# Krita: How to apply a stroke effect like in Photoshop

Tags: stroke, krita

when cleaning images from their background I always used Photoshops *Stroke Effect*, which applied a coloured stroke around any visible pixels. This is extremely helpful with nearly invisible pixels or whole areas of pixels, which I can easily erase then.

So how can I accomplish the same effect with Krita?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Krita has Layer Styles - so you can do it by adding a stroke effect, similar to Photoshop.

The Layer Styles window is under *Layer >  Layer Style*

Here I have set a red stroke on a random black shape which I painted with the Paint Brush.

[image]